# NextJS can't get use state to run even with use client

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, onclick

For the above code, I am trying to run the useState to handle the click of an x to close the sidebar. Still very new to NextJS so I added the "use client" to be able to use hooks but nothing happens when I click on the x.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don’t provide code in a link, but in text, and even at best, in a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use nav variable in your template, that's why nothing happens.

You can use React's conditional rendering, e.g.

```
{nav && <p>Navigation is shown!</p>}
```

You can read more in [the official docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: I added the nav variable and some operators but nothing is happening still

Comment: you have to add "use client" to the document was the biggest hurdle I did not know